# Подскажите с сообщением об успешной отправке в методе .post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Помогите разобраться в строке server.post(....), не пойму как туда вставить сообщение об успешной отправке, в документации подобного случая не нашел, хотя может плохо искал, в основном везде примеры с .post().done().fail(), а тут через bind сделано

```
app.on('send order', bind(function(){
  if(app.contacts.isValid()){
    // Preparing order.
    var order = {
      price             : this.cart.totalPrice(),
      emailOrdersTo     : this.emailOrdersTo,
      site              : window.location.host,
      currency          : this.currency,
      language          : this.language
    }
    extend(order, this.contacts.toJSON())
    extend(order, this.cart.toJSON())

    // Clearing the cart and showing success message.
    this.cart.removeAll()
    var message = '<div class="cart"><div class="cart-message">'
    + escapeHtml(t('orderSent')) + '</div></div>'

    //this.cartPopupView.show(message)

    //Редирект на страницу благодарности
    window.location.href = "/store-thanks.html";

    // Цель Яндекс Метрики
    yaCounter34344860.reachGoal('zakaz_inet');

    // Sending order to server.
    server.post(this.baseUrl + '/form/storeformprocessor.php', order, bind(function(err){
        err = "as";
      if(err){
        var message = '<div class="cart"><div class="cart-message cart-message-error">'
        + escapeHtml(t('orderFailed')) + '</div></div>'
        this.cartPopupView.show(message)
      }
    }, this))
  }
}, this))
```